# Handling CORS form submissions

Tags: html, forms, go

I have a very simple form being served from localhost:3000

```
<form id="my-HTML-form" action="http://localhost:8080" method="POST">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" />
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" />
    <input type="hidden" name="form-id" value="login" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

On localhost:8080, I have a very simple go server:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    // Start the server
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    serverErr := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
    if serverErr != nil {
        log.Println("Error starting server")
        log.Fatal(serverErr)
    }
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    log.Println(r.Header.Get("Origin"))
    log.Println(r.Method)

    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Accept, Accept-Encoding, Authorization, Content-Length, Content-Type, Origin, X-CSRF-Token")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
}
```

When I submit my form, I actually receive two requests! A POST and a GET! Here is my console after a SINGLE submit:

```
$ http://localhost:3000
$ POST
$ 
$ GET
```

Notice the GET request doesn't have an origin attached to it. I'm trying to perform some logic and then redirect the user to different url's based on success or failure. But I can't do this because the GET request immediately follows the POST request. I can use AJAX, no problem, but I was hoping to find a solution for a simple html form submission.

Any thoughts, ideas? Do all browsers follow the [POST/Redirect/Get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) paradigm and I'm SOL?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you posting to the same server? I don't see a cross-origin request here. The GET is likely to be the browser requesting `/favicon.ico` - if you log the full request you'll see the path.

Comment: @elithrar Thanks much. This was correct. I had other logic in my server, and because the second request was a GET request for the favicon (r.URL == "/favicon.ico") and for some reason didn't include the origin header, I was sending back a 401. I'm now checking r.URL for the favicon and simply calling "return" in the handler function - not 200, 401, or any other code, and it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your form action is `action="http://localhost:8080"` because you said this is a cross origin request.

The second GET request is the request for favicon (as elithrar points out in comments). Just do a `log.Println(r.URL)` to make sure. I am not sure why the browser does not add origin header to it though.

You can redirect requests by replacing `w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)` by for example,
`http.Redirect(w, r, "http://localhost:3000/success.html", http.StatusSeeOther)`.

Comment: Thanks much. This was correct. I had other logic in my server, and because the second request was a GET request for the favicon (r.URL == "/favicon.ico") and for some reason didn't include the origin header, I was sending back a 401. I'm now checking r.URL for the favicon and simply calling "return" in the handler function - not 200, 401, or any other code, and it's working.